# svchost keeps changing publisher to empty value and back

Tags: windows-7, windows, svchost

My svchost.exe keeps changing it's application publisher from 'Microsoft Windows' to an empty value and back in 2 seconds. The path of svchost.exe doing this is 'c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe'. I have scanned the exe with my anti-virus scanner, Avast, and no threat was found. What might be causing this?

Comment: Windows exe's don't have a standard attribute called "Publisher", through they do have fields for "Product Name" and "Copyright".  What utility are you using to view the process or executable that is presenting the field as "Publisher"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The svchost.exe is a facilitator for running .dlls. By itself it does nothing. It only helps those dlls to run. So the application publisher may change depending on the .dll that is being run.